# Kubernetes Ingress Whitelist IP for host

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-config, nginx-ingress

How can I whitelist IP addresses for different hosts, but for the same path?

example.com - should be without whitelist. All others must be whitelisted.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: login.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: login
          servicePort: 4444
        path: /
  - host: admin.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: admin
          servicePort: 3333
        path: /
  - host: api.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: api
          servicePort: 2222
        path: /
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: wp
          servicePort: 1111
        path: /
```

Comment: so, there is no way to do it
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5260

Answer (score 4, accepted):

annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "1.1.1.1/24"

Comment: Hello, this will cover the entire ingress, for each host.
But I need a whitelist only for login.example.com, admin.example.com and api.example.com

Answer (score 2):

Basically @ANISH gave you a good idea about  [nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#whitelist-source-range), where you can start.

> You can specify allowed client IP source ranges through the
>   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range annotation. The
>   value is a comma separated list of CIDRs, e.g. 10.0.0.0/24,172.10.0.1.
>
> To configure this setting globally for all Ingress rules, the
>   whitelist-source-range value may be set in the NGINX ConfigMap.

However, if you dont want to apply it to all your ingress rules - just create 2 separate ingresses. 1 for whitelisted hosts and second for your example.com host

Comment: hello! thanks for your answer. Actually i know about this ability (make 2 ingresses), but I'm trying to find another solution to avoid 2 ingresses.

Comment: Interesting fact, i'v created second ingress with nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range annotation, and it's have the same external IP as first one! unexpected behaviour for me, i thought that will be different IP for second ingress